# gtest problem with main function

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a line.cpp with a main function and some other functions I want to test.
Then I have my utest.cpp with my test cases and another main function to call them.

A solution would be to just comment the main function and then test, but that is not the solution I am looking for.
I understand that I can not have multiple main files in my project, but how can I test my functions? Because in the [robot_pose_ekf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf) package, there are also two main files and it works.

The CMake relevant part looks like this:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(line src/line.cpp)

rosbuild_add_gtest(test/utest test/utest.cpp)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64123/gtest-problem-with-main-function/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2013-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A simple solution is to move the functions you want to test into another source file, with a header to declare their interfaces. You can compile that into a library or just add it to the source file lists of both the `line` and `test/utest` targets.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1